# How to create a join query between two entities in FIWARE orion?

Tags: fiware-orion

I have two entites A (postings) and B (users) with a many to one relationship and I want to do an SQL like join to list posts and users together.
I tried the following query, but it only returns an empty array.
I could not find any other documentation regarding this, all tutorials only refer to one id.

```
https://{{orion}}/v2/entities?q=Post.createdBy==User.id&options=count,keyValues&limit=100
```

I also tried this variant, but the same result:

```
https://{{orion}}/v2/entities?q=createdBy==id&options=count,keyValues&limit=100
```

And I checked that there is at least one entity which matches I manually checked

```
https://{{orion}}/v2/entities?q=createdBy==urn:ngsi-ld:User:78bc5cac26d1b3abe27cb2cf94b1015a3710958f
```

This query above returns an entity.

```
|      Post        |     |     User     |
|------------------|     |--------------|
| ID               |     | ID           |
| Type             |     | Type         |
| Message          |     | Username     |
| CreatedBy: UserId|
```

In orion the datatype:

```
   "createdBy": {
            "type": "Relationship",
            "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:User:78bc5cac26d1b3abe27cb2cf94b1015a3710958f",
            "metadata": {}
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do that kind of join operations using the NGSI API provided by Orion.

The NGSI API is oriented to context management, that is, retrieving and updating context information in the form of entities and their attributes. It is not designed to be a SQL-style language, which would involve a lot of complexity. Orion is a context broker, not a relational database ;)

Fortunately, that kind of join operations can be done by the client, doing several queries to Orion.